# Define an association with a filter?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Is there a way to create an association in entity framework that always applies a "where" filter?

Here's an example:
Suppose that I have a database that uses "soft" deletes -- so there is a "deleted" column in every table.

So if I have a Customer entity that is related to Address (1:0..n), I would like for the Addresses navigation property to always be filtered on the deleted flag, so that if I go Customer.Addresses, the collection will only return Addresses where deleted == 0.

Anyone know of some way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there isn't.

Same reason you can't have a *conditional* foreign key.

A workaround could be to use TPH on the **Address** table:

- Create abstract entity called **Address**
- Create derived entities called **AddressDeleted** and **AddressNotDeleted**
- Set the discriminator mapping (AddressDeleted maps to Address when Deleted = 0)
- Create a navigational property between Customer and AddressDeleted.

So when you do `ctx.Customer.Include("AddressDeleted").Single()` it will only return the addresses that are flagged as deleted.

Or you could defined an association to Address, and use `ctx.Customer.Addresses.OfType<AddressDeleted>()`.

Does that solve your problem?

Comment: It might be the solution -- I need to play with it some more -- I'm fairly new to EF.  Do you know off hand if there would be a way to get the association to work the way I need if I either modified the T4 template, or if I generated my own POCO's and used them with EF (I haven't worked with either of these capabilities yet)

Comment: The thing you need to remember is that a navigational property is like a "conceptual foreign key". It is used to uniquely identify record(s), the same way a FK in the database does. Navigational properties either need to map to a FK in the database, or a custom referential constraint. But even with that custom constraint, it needs to have a 1-1 map both sides of the relationship - can't be conditional. TPH is very easy to do - have a read of this blog/walkthrough http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2010/01/24/table-per-hierarchy-inheritance-in-entity-framework.aspx